# Performant non-realtime phase accumulator

Tags: python

I try to implement a phase accumulator in Python which takes as input a lookup table (lut), a frequency (f), an amplitude (a) and modulation signals (fm, am). My current class works fine but i want to optimize it as much as i can because it is the bottleneck of my script. Right now my class looks like this:

```
class Signal:
    def __new__(self, lut, mod=False, f=1, fm=False, a=1, am=False, length=1, fs=48000):
        length = int(np.rint(fs * length))
        signal = np.zeros(length)

        phi = f / fs
        phase = 0

        for i in range(length):
            if (hasattr(fm, "__len__")):
                phi_fm = phi + (fm[i] * phi)
                phase += phi_fm
            else:
                phase += phi
            phase %= 1
            idx = int(np.rint(phase * len(lut))) % len(lut)
            signal[i] = lut[idx]

        if (hasattr(am, "__len__")):
            signal *= 1 - am

        if (mod == 'am'):
            signal = _to_am_range(signal, a=a)
        elif (mod == 'fm'):
            signal = _to_fm_range(signal, a=a)
        else:
            signal = _to_audio_range(signal, a=a)

        return signal
```

My plan is to optimize it by using matrix operations instead of iterative operations. But I am not sure if this is even possible for all iterations. For example I can calulate phi as follows:

```
phi = np.array([f / fs for i in range(length)])
```

That works fine, but then I have to calculate the phase array which is basically the accumulative sum of phi % 1 up to a given index, so:

```
phase[0] = phi[0] % 1
phase[1] = phi[0] + phi[1] % 1
phase[2] = phi[0] + phi[1] + phi[2] % 1
...
```

I could easily calculate this with a loop, but maybe there is a faster way? And any other advice on performance increase is highly appreciated as well!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the function to see what takes up most time? I don't see any major culprits, except you could maybe cache `len(lut)` instead of calling it twice pr iteration in the `for` loop (not that it gives much improvement...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll try to do some profiling. Another thing that came to my mind while taking a walk: would it maybe be better to use a function instead of a class? Sorry if this is a dumb question, i'm fairly new to programming and don't really understand how everything works on a deeper level.

Comment: I hadn't noticed, but yes I would definitely put this in a function. Either on it's own, or in a method (a member-function in a class). It would surprise me if that had any influence on performance though... If length is a big number, you could try parallelizing the for-loop

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty big number, so i will try that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's pretty easy to parallelize loops in threads (if you're mostly I/O bound) or processes (if you are CPU bound) -- see here for a demo of both concepts: https://github.com/kokke/concurrency-demo-py

Comment: Ah great, thank you! I will definitely look into that. I profiled the function as well and it looks like there is no much room for improvement. I tried a few things and everything was a bit slower than my initial solution...

Comment: I added an answer, distilling "the fruits of our discussions" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our discussion in the comments, I think something like the code below could be a viable solution for you:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor, wait, ALL_COMPLETED

def process(i, fm, phi, lut, signal):
    if (hasattr(fm, "__len__")):
        phi_fm = phi + (fm_i * phi)
        phase += phi_fm
    else:
        phase += phi
    phase %= 1
    idx = int(np.rint(phase * len(lut))) % len(lut)
    signal[i] = lut[idx]

def make_signal(lut, mod=False, f=1, fm=False, a=1, am=False, length=1, fs=48000):
    length = int(np.rint(fs * length))
    signal = np.zeros(length)

    phi = f / fs
    phase = 0

    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=nthreads)
    futures = list()

    for i in range(length):
        fut = executor.submit(process, (i, fm, phi, lut, signal,))
        futures.append(fut)

    wait(futures, return_when = ALL_COMPLETED)

    if (hasattr(am, "__len__")):
        signal *= 1 - am

    if (mod == 'am'):
        signal = _to_am_range(signal, a=a)
    elif (mod == 'fm'):
        signal = _to_fm_range(signal, a=a)
    else:
        signal = _to_audio_range(signal, a=a)

    return signal
```

I've changed the class-definition to a function and given it a new name ('make_signal'). I've also created a function 'process' that gets called concurrently.

I haven't tested the code! I did not have an easy way to give it inputs..

Comment: Thanks, i will test it! :)

Comment: hmm it gives me an error: BrokenProcessPool: A child process terminated abruptly, the process pool is not usable anymore. (its in the line which starts with fut = ...) Sadly i don't have any idea what it means :D

Comment: and the inputs lut, fm and am are all just signals with the same length, i use simple 1darrays or lists which are normalized between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1 but the normalization doesnt really matter

Comment: Are you running directly in the REPL/console or are you saving to file etc.? I've only seen that error when I've been using the REPL directly.

Comment: So i tried a few things, but when i run it as a .py-script from the command line i get the same error. It says that i should add 'if __name__ == '__main__':' in front but when i do that it freezes... but i think i get how it should work, i will probably find a solution soon!